# How can I install gnome-icon-theme:i386?

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, ibus

I want to install `ibus:i386`. However, I get an error saying that this package depends on `gnome-icon-theme:i386`, which is not installable. Indeed, when I run `apt-get install gnome-icon-theme:i386`, I get an error saying that there are no installable candidates.

The `universe` repository is enabled, and here is what I get when I run `sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme:i386`:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package gnome-icon-theme:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  file-roller:i386 file-roller gnome-icon-theme-full

E: Package 'gnome-icon-theme:i386' has no installation candidate
```

How can I install this package to get this dependency check to pass?

Answer (score 2):

`gnome-icon-theme` is in the Universe repository, which you'll have to enable by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
```

and then run the update by:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install the package by:

```
apt-get install gnome-icon-theme
```

You can also install `gnome-icon-theme-full` if the above one did not work for any reason. Note that these packages have multiarch support.

Comment: The universe repository was enabled. I pasted the output of the command in my question.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? You can also use `gnome-icon-theme-full`

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. And, using `gnome-theme-icon-full:i386` has the same effect. Maybe the reason for this is the `:i386` suffix? I'm looking to install the 32-bit version on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Any specific reason for that? Install without `i383`

Comment: Well, as I said in my question, I'm trying to install `ibus:i386`, and I get a message saying `ibus:i386 : Depends: gnome-icon-theme:i386 but it is not installable`. I'm trying to get that message to disappear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34789/discussion-between-parham-doustdar-and-ron).